# CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead

Tags: python, jwt, fastapi, python-jose

```
INFO:Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit) 
INFO:Started reloader process [27528] using statreload
C:Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jose\backends\cryptography_backend.py:18:
CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes 
instead from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes, int_to_bytes 
INFO: Started server process [8912]
INFO: Waiting for application startup. 
INFO: Application startup complete.
```

**I am new to FastAPI as I was implementing the JWT token in my project the APIs are working as it should be, but each time I start the server it shows this warning.**

I have imported jwt from jose and CryptContext from passlib.context
python version 3.9

I really love to know what is the reason behind this!

Answer (score 3):

The deprecation warning is caused by how the `python-jose` library loads the integer values from bytes. This is not related to fastapi, but is an issue in the library you're using. However, the issue was fixed in `python-jose` five days ago (2021-04-29), and will be present in the next release.

You can [see the change in the commit](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/commit/b899276cc3e46f6c304f81687404294764612852) on Github. For now you can ignore the warning, but as soon as an upgraded version of `python-jose` is released you should upgrade to the new version.

Answer (score 3):

Try to upgrade cryptography package to the newest available version

```
python3 -m pip install -U cryptography
```